Could I run into problems by connecting +VBUS and +5V directly without any protection even thought I intend on using only one power source at a time?
In my schematic I have 2 power sources, a 3 cell LiPo battery and +5V from the USB VBUS. The +12V from the LiBo battery are stepped down to +5V using a buck converter and from there the +5V are again stepped down to 3.3V using a linear regulator. When I program the MCU I would like to be able to use the USB as the power source so I don't have to connect and recharge the battery every time. Since I am the only one that will be working with the PCB and I will make sure to not plug in the battery and USB at the same time, I was wondering if I can just connect VBUS to the input of the linear regulator (like in the screenshot). I am not sure what happens when the VBUS goes to the buck converter, can the +5V from the USB damage the switching converter?

A diode does not cost very much, nor does it take up a lot of space on the board. Speaking from experience, "I'll always remember" is a recipe for self-recrimination down the line.

Do you mean I should add 2 diodes, one for the +5V coming from the buck converter and one for the VBUS and make sure that the voltage drop across the diodes doesn't exceed 0.6V? (I need at least +4.4V at the input of the linear regulator to get an accurate output of about 3.3V)

I would add both since, as @Justme said, you are assuming that the LM25965 is fine being back-fed. < 600mV drop is achievable but there are also alternatives to the AMS1117 that don't need 1.1V of overhead.

So there is at least three things here.

If 12V is enabled, the regulator makes 5V to your USB connector. If you are absolutely sure you never accidentally have anything connected then go ahead. However, if you ever make a mistake, such as have a desktop or laptop computer connected, your buck regulator may damage the computer motherboard.

There is 330 uF plus 22 uF worth of capacitors on 5V/VBUS line. USB devices are required to have max 10uF. Plugging 352 uF worth of capacitor to your computer may damage it, or at least may trip overcurrent protection, and if implemented with a fuse, the fuse may blow and your computer USB port will not work.

So it's the least problem is the buck chip getting damaged if 5V is fed externally from USB. The regulator data sheet does not explicitly forbid this, or say under which condition it would be or be not allowed. You have to assume that this is not an issue.


So you may into run other problems that you did not expect.
It will be a foolproof solution to add two diodes, so that your USB implementation is safe and never damages your computer and has a sensible input capacitance. One diode from USB, one diode from buck output.

So even if I add the 2 diodes, I would still have the 22uF on the VBUS line which greatly exceeds 10uF, so I assume I would still have problems with the USB?

@Robert Yes you would, unless you change it to something smaller. Which you should obviously do. There is no reason to have 22uF directly on LDO input and output. However, 22uF is still much better than 330+ uF.

In this case I will change the linear regulator for one that does not require more than 10uF capacitance at the input and I will also add two diodes(probably schottky diodes), one for the USB and one for the +5V from the buck converter.

@Robert You don't need to change the regulator for that reason, because it does not even require 22uF or 10uF  input capacitor. Beware that schottky diodes leak more current in reverse than standars diodes.

I've read the datasheet of the ams1117-3.3 again and I realized it talks about a 22uF capacitor at the output of the linear converter. Do you know if I should place an input capacitor at all? I didn't see any mention of it in the data sheet.

@Robert A small bypass like 1uF to 4.7uF on input is fine. And the output does not need to be 22uF either. The datasheet says smaller can be used. The datasheet also talks about 22uF tantalum, but you have not drawn a tantalum capacitor. Ceramic caps have significantly lower impedance and may even make the regulator expecting a large tantalum with higher impedance unstable. You might want to add a small series resistor to the ceramic capacitor, maybe in the order of 0.1 to 0.5 ohms.

got it! As the input capacitor I can use for example a 4.7uF ceramic capacitor and for the output capacitor I either use a 22uF or smaller tantalum capacitor or add a resistor between 0.1 to 0.5 ohms in series with the 22uF ceramic capacitor.  Could you please confirm that I understood this correctly?

@Robert I think so. Now to think of it, it might be better to change to another regulator that will work directly with small ceramic caps.

Sorry for bothering you with so many questions, but I was wondering now if I have already designed and assembled a PCB that only has the power converters with the battery input and it worked as intended, the buck converter output was +5V on the dot and the linear converter's output was around ~ +3.35V does that mean that it works just fine in this configuration and eventually I should just change the input capacitor of the linear regulator to fit the USB requirements and add the 2 diodes?

@Robert the capacitors won't change the voltages so it should work.

Thank you very much for the help! Have a great night(or day)!
